# Windows Authentication lost on IIS

Tags: authentication, iis

In my IIS 8.5 inside a Windows Server 2012 R2 when I create a site the Authentication options does not appear
[image: IIS]

However in my IIS 7.5 inside a Windows Servr 2008 R2 I see this

[image: IIS2]

How can I add the rest of authentications in IIS 8.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding this in programs & features

[image: iis]

Comment: I'm trying but it tells me that "you can accept tour own answer tomorrow"

Comment: if your issue is resolved I request you to mark the solution as an answer it will help other people who face similar issues